# Drupal on nginx: 404 Error

Tags: 7

I'm migrating my drupal websites from a server running with Apache web server to a Nginx server. The problem is, I can't access any of my websites on the nginx server. It redirects me to a 404 error page for all websites.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Were you using clean URL's before the migration?  If this is the case, than you may need to set up mod_rewrite only for nginx. I have not used the server but found this article on how to achieve the same.

http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpRewriteModule

Not sure if this is your problem though, although it might be.